# How to access pathParameter directly in Gorouter

Tags: flutter, dart, gorouter

i'm new to the flutter
i'm curious how to access pathParameter using gorouter, am i doing wrong or what?

```
GoRouter initializeRoute(){
  return GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: AppRoute.main,
        name: "main",
        builder: (context, state) => const MainPortofolioView(),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            name: "profile",
            path: AppRoute.profile,
            builder: (context, state) => const ProfilePortofolioView(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: "projects",
            path: AppRoute.projects,
            builder: (context, state) => const ProjectPortofolioView(),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                name: "project",
                path: AppRoute.project,
                builder: (context, state){
                  final data = state.extra as ProjectInformationTileEntity;
                  return ProjectInformationView(projectID: data.projectID);
                },
              )
            ]
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: "contact",
            path: AppRoute.contact,
            builder: (context, state) => const ContactPortofolioView(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: "debug",
            path: AppRoute.debug,
            builder: (context,state) => const DebugView()
          )
        ]
      )
    ]
  );
}
```

so i try to access for example profile route which is "http://localhost:49597/profile", why it's not working? same also on the others
[This path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wivXz.png)

Comment: You have the server properly configured to deliver your app despite the extra path?

Comment: And you've configured this (otherwise, it's a hashpath): GoRouter.setUrlPathStrategy(UrlPathStrategy.path);

Comment: Hii Randal i saw you on Flutter Observable, how to properly config? any documentation? i can't find GoRouter.setUrlPathStrategy instead i usePathUrlStrategy() from flutter it self, so that fix my problem, but still when i move to the next route e.g context.go(blabla) i still don't see the current route in my browser